# React Redux Toolkit Typescript - A non-serializable value was detected in the state

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I have seen many other answers to this question but nothing that solves my issue.

I understand that I am not supposed to be using classes, but I have tried to remove anything non-serialisable from my classes. I guess the question is whether it's ever possible to use typescript classes in Redux state. But all of my classes seem to work except when I try to create a new instance of Envelope.

```
export class SequenceStep {
    time: number = 0;
    note: number = 64;
    velocity: number = 100;
    gateLength: number = 0.8;
}

export class MidiSettings {
    midiInputDeviceId: string = "";
    midiInputDeviceName: string = "";
    midiInputChannelNum: number = -1;
    midiOutputDeviceId: string = "";
    midiOutputDeviceName: string = "";
    midiOutputChannelNum: number = 0;
}

export class EnvelopePoint {
    // time in steps
    time: number = 0;
    value: number = 0;
}

export class Envelope {
    id: string = "";
    controller: string = "";
    points: Array<EnvelopePoint> = [];
    locked: boolean = true;
    length: number = 8;
    division: number = 8;
    mode: string = "loop";
    trigger: string = "first";
    type: string = "envelope";
}

export class Sequence {
    _id: string = "";
    name: string = "";
    text: string = "";
    user_name: string = "";
    user_id: string = "";
    steps: Array<SequenceStep> = []
    tempo: number = 120.0;
    length: number = 8;
    numSteps: number = 8;
    division: number = 8;
    midiSettings: MidiSettings = new MidiSettings();
    currentEnvelopeId: string = "";
    envelopes: Array<Envelope> = []
}
```

Here is the offending reducer. 'createEnvelope' causes the error. The others seem to work properly.

```
interface SequenceSliceState {
    value: Sequence;
    division: number;
}

const initialState : SequenceSliceState = {
    value: new Sequence(),
    division: 8
}

export const sequenceSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'sequence',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        sequenceLoad: (state, payloadAction) => {
            state.value = payloadAction.payload.sequence;
            return state;
        },
        sequenceName: (state, payloadAction) => {
            state.value.name = payloadAction.payload;
            return state
        },
        createEnvelope: (state, action) => {
            const controller = action.payload.controller
            var sequence: Sequence = state.value
            var newEnvelopeId = uuidv4()
            var newEnvelope = new Envelope()    //newEnvelopeId, controller.name);
            newEnvelope.id = newEnvelopeId
            newEnvelope.controller = controller.name
            newEnvelope.points = [{ time: 0, value: 0}, ]

            if (sequence.envelopes == null) {
                console.log(`sequenceSlice - how can sequence.envelopes be null?`)
                sequence.envelopes = [newEnvelope];
            }
            else {
                state.value.envelopes = [...state.value.envelopes, newEnvelope];
            }

            state.value.currentEnvelopeId = newEnvelopeId;
            return state
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my mistake was simply to use redux in a typescript project. I ended up on Redux because my research involved undo/redo. I don't see redux being recommended for new projects. I am refactoring with Zustrand.